# Opentelemetry Data persistency

Tags: database, docker-compose, persistence, open-telemetry

I am try to integrate my application with OpenTelemetry. In the current solution openTelemetry collector export data directly to the jaeger. But I want to use Database between them and want to send data to OpenTelemetry data to that database and then configure jaeger to retriever that data from database. Main purpose is using that data base it should be configure to any another tool like zipkin or etc... I include my current docker-composer.yaml file and otel-collector-config.yaml file with this. Can someone help me with this. (if it is mongodb or postgress timescale db it will be nice. But any solutions are ok)

docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  # Jaeger
  jaeger-all-in-one:
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
    ports:
      - "16686:16686"
      - "14268:14268"
      - "14250:14250"
  # Collector
  otel-collector:
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector:latest
    command: ["--config=/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml"]
    volumes:
      - ./opentelemetry/otel-collector-config.yaml:/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml:Z
    ports:
      - "13133:13133" # Health_check extension
      - "4317:4317"   # OTLP gRPC receiver
      - "4318:4318" # HTTP
    depends_on:
      - jaeger-all-in-one  
networks:

volumes:
```

otel-collector-config.yaml

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: otel-collector:4317
      http:
        cors:
          allowed_origins:
            - "https://*"
            - "http://*"
          allowed_headers:
            - "*"

exporters:
  jaeger:
    endpoint: jaeger-all-in-one:14250
    tls:
      insecure: true

processors:
  batch:

extensions:
  health_check:

service:
  extensions: [health_check]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [jaeger]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say your desired solution is overengineered. OTEL native solution is to send traces to multiple trace backends (your "database" term) directly. Example config snippet:

```
...
exporters:
  jaeger:
    <jaeger-configs>
  zipkin:
    <zipkin-configs>
  <another-exporter>:
    <another-exporter-configs>
...
service:
  extensions: [health_check]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [jaeger, zipkin, <another-exporter>]
```

You have available many types of exporter - https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter (BTW no your desired DB `mongodb or postgress timescale db` is supported)